# How to count length of column while some rows have NaN in it?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas dataframe. In column I have list. But, some rows NaN. I want to find length of each list, in case it is NaN, I want 0 as length.

```
My_column
[1, 2]-> should return 2
[] -> should return 0
NaN -> should return 0
```

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
df['column'].str.len().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the item is a **list**:

- **If it is a list** - identify the **length** of that list
- **If it is not a list** (eg. np.nan) - then set to **zero**.

```
output = [len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 0 for x in df['column']]
```

Here is an example using your inputs

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [['a','b'], np.nan, []]})

output = [len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 0 for x in df['column']]

print(output)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[2, 0, 0]
```